# POST method with ajax and express

Tags: ajax

I want to send and object model to my server

```
$.getJSON(request, function(data){
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {data},
            contentType: "application/json",
            url: "/movie",
            success: function(){
                console.log("Movie data send");
            }
});
```

express:

```
app.post("/movie", function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body.data);
});
```

The error i'm getting on the console browser is:

```
POST http://localhost:8888/movie 400 (Bad Request)
send @ jquery.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ session:47
i @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
A @ jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:4
```

and in my server console:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token d
```

What am I doing wrong? I checked other similar questions but I don't know how to apply their solutions to my case

EDIT: I changed the code, now it looks like this:

```
var movie = JSON.stringify(data);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: movie,
            dataType: "json",
            url: "/session/movie",
            success: function(){
                console.log("Movie data send");
            }
        });
```

server:

```
app.post("/session/movie", function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body.movie);
});
```

And now I'm getting undefined on the server console ...

Comment: Your second attempt looks better but a) you should keep the `contentType` param, and b) should it simply be `console.log(req.body)`? Your JSON data probably doesn't have a `movie` property

Comment: @phil It was the movie property, I changed to 'req.body' only and it worked, thanks